# How to find current a0 parameter in Cardano node

Tags: cardano

Is their any way to get current value of a0 parameter from node.
The parameters are not found in configuration file. These are not passed as parameter when the node is started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the protocol parameters using `cardano-cli`:

```
$ cardano-cli query protocol-parameters --mary-era --mainnet

{
    "poolDeposit": 500000000,
    "protocolVersion": {
        "minor": 0,
        "major": 4
    },
    "minUTxOValue": 1000000,
    "decentralisationParam": 0.12,
    "maxTxSize": 16384,
    "minPoolCost": 340000000,
    "minFeeA": 44,
    "maxBlockBodySize": 65536,
    "minFeeB": 155381,
    "eMax": 18,
    "extraEntropy": {
        "tag": "NeutralNonce"
    },
    "maxBlockHeaderSize": 1100,
    "keyDeposit": 2000000,
    "nOpt": 500,
    "rho": 3.0e-3,
    "tau": 0.2,
    "a0": 0.3 
}
```

`a0` is the last key in the above output.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Blockfrost API you can get parameters at the time of each epoch including the a0 parameter:

[https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/epochs/{number}/parameters](https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/epochs/%7Bnumber%7D/parameters)

API docs:

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Epochs/paths/~1epochs~1%7Bnumber%7D~1parameters/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Epochs/paths/%7E1epochs%7E1%7Bnumber%7D%7E1parameters/get)